# Subclassing namedtuple, __new__ and __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, namedtuple

I am very new to Python and am currently using Python 3.4

Right now, I am apparently banging my head to figure out how best to create a customized immutable object by subclassing 'namedtuple'.

Here are my code that works without errors but I am getting way too many warning messages from my good friend PyCharm, so it was set upon me to find out if I am doing this correctly.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Aloe(namedtuple('Plant', [
    'name',
    'color',
    'loveliness'
])):

    def __new__(cls, params):
        return super(Aloe, cls).__new__(
            cls,
            params.get('name'),
            params.get('color'),
            params.get('loveliness')
        )

    def __init__(self, params):
        print(self.name)
        super(Aloe, self).__init__()
```

When I call it, I get this.

```
>>> aloe = Aloe(params)
>>> print(aloe)
Aloe(name='aloey', color='green', loveliness='extreme')
```

---

The first of warning come from `__new__` block.

All my `params.get('FIELD_NAME')` are blamed for '**Unexpected argument**'.

Funny thing is, if my remove the arguments, I got,

`TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument:`

What does this thing really want me to do?!

---

The second of warning come from `__init__` block.

`super(Aloe, self).__init__()` is blamed for '**Parameter 'typename' unfilled**'

So I gave it a good `'Plant'` as the desired 'typename'. Then I got,

`TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`

(ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

---

Back to the point,

1. My code is working, but I get loads of warnings from PyCharm.
2. There seems absolutely no way I can satisfy PyCharm.

So, I am concerned that I might be neglecting the *Pythonic* way of handling things. If I am, I wish I could use some tips.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled as to why you have an `__init__` method, but otherwise the code looks fine. Find the documentation on how to tell PyCharm the code is fine, and move on.

Comment: Whatever pycharm says your code looks unpythonic to me and I don't understand why you are doing that instead of just `Aloe = namedtuple('Aloe', ['name', 'color', 'loveliness'])` and then `aloe = Aloe(**params)`.

Comment: @Goyo I am trying to extend namedtuple because i want to put more customized methods under the subclass for communications with my database. Do you think I am thinking in the right direction in this case?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Admittedly relying on PyCharm, I put __init__ method because I was getting `Signature is not compatible to __init__` warning from `__new__`. I think I should not puzzle you. So I will remove it and be content with the fact I am no longer creating puzzles :D

Comment: @Goyo: that won't set default values (`None` in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm is being overly protective here, and incorrect to boot. However, if all you wanted to do is provide some default values, I'd use a factory method:

```
class Aloe(namedtuple('Plant', 'name color loveliness')):
    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, name=None, color=None, loveliness=None, **ignored):
        return cls(name, color, loveliness)
```

and use `**params` when creating one:

```
Aloe.from_row(**params)
```

This applies the key-value pairs from `params` as separate keyword arguments. Missing keys will set to `None`, extra keys are captured in `**ignored` and ignored.

If your database rows will *always* produce exactly the right 3 keys in a row dictionary, don't even bother with a factory method, just directly use a `namedtuple` and the above `**params` syntax:

```
Aloe(**params)
```